# Catch Spring runtime exception with Spring AOP

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

For logging purposes, we're trying to catch various Spring's runtime exceptions via Spring's own AOP and I must say I've been unsuccessful, so I would appreciate any ideas as to how to approach this.

I've tried something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {

@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* org.springframwork.oxm..*(..))", throwing = "exception")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void adviseSpringErrorEvents(JoinPoint joinPoint, final UnmarshallingFailureException exception) throws Throwable {

         LOG.debug(this.getClass().getSimpleName() + " - Error message advice fired on method: " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
     }
}
```

The class is autoproxied and the rest of the advice in the aspect class correctly fire, so there has to be a problem with the AspectJ expression.

UPDATE: The code inside the method does not run and it is not my intention to catch the exception in the advice.

Any ideas? Thx in advance.

P.S. Spring framework version is 3.0.6.

Comment: Do you mean by unsuccessful that this code does not even run or that it does not catch the exception? - cause if you want to stop the exception from propagating you'll want @AroundAdvice instead.

Comment: This code does not even run. The debugger does not stop at the breakpoint inside the given method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple of things that stand out to me:

1. Your point cut is for the spring package that the exception you are trying to catch it is in, it should be where you are trying to join `execution(* com.mypackage..*(..))`.
2. You are throwing throwable but you do not need to declare anything being thrown.  The exception being advised of will not propagate through this code.

Things to try:

1. Expand your exception parameter to `Exception`.  Maybe the exception you are looking for is in a different hierarchy.
2. Widen the pointcut to * package level - but probably best not to do both 1 and 2 at the same time.
3. Increase logging to a more severe level to be sure it is not getting gobbled by your logging framework.

Comment: Yes, I've tried these things even before I posted the question, however, I didn't manage provoke the advice into firing. Could be Maven is playing tricks with my classpath and I just can't see what's going on. I will try a few tricks tomorrow - if I manage to fire it, I'll let you know.

Comment: I think the main problem is that your pointcut is for the org.springframework.oxm package and I doubt this is what you want, it should be the package for your code.

Comment: My thoughts exactly - that's why I first started with something like `com.mypackage..*(..)` expression, but since that didn't work, I figured - let's intercept the exception right we're it is thrown and that has to be Spring's OXM package.

Comment: Your join point needs to be a spring bean residing in your application context - and at a guess, the stuff in org.spring framework.oxm is probably not going to be spring beans in their own right.  You could test it by putting a Before or AfterAdvice on that package at see if it is ever invoked.

Comment: That's a valid point. So, can we conclude that the only way to catch Spring runtime exceptions is within our Spring beans? No other, sneaky ways of achieving this with AOP?

Comment: If you have configured one of the oxm marshallers in your spring context you should be able to use that as a join point and see exceptions that are thrown out from there.  I have not used oxm before but it's possible that these exceptions are thrown through layers that you can't join on.  Consider increasing the logging level on the oxm package itself instead.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9946/discussion-between-quantum-and-krock)

Comment: Thank you for your time and your efforts - I've forgotten to accept your answer. Still haven't had the time to thoroughly think about the problem of catching Runtime exceptions with AOP, but if as soon as I get the time, I'll post back here.